# Javascript Redirect url no found

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to redirect to another url but i tried find string to wwww something but its not found is not found

```
var miski = jaython;
(function (jaran, brookston) {
  var mikial = jaython, swarnim = jaran();
  while (!![]) {
    try {
      var breyanne = parseInt(mikial(169)) / 1 * (parseInt(mikial(178)) / 2) + -parseInt(mikial(172)) / 3 + -parseInt(mikial(147)) / 4 * (parseInt(mikial(141)) / 5) + parseInt(mikial(173)) / 6 * (-parseInt(mikial(175)) / 7) + parseInt(mikial(149)) / 8 + -parseInt(mikial(164)) / 9 + -parseInt(mikial(146)) / 10 * (-parseInt(mikial(161)) / 11);
      if (breyanne === brookston) break; else swarnim.push(swarnim.shift());
    } catch (akyng) {
      swarnim.push(swarnim.shift());
    }
  }
}(romane, 958116));
var x = document[miski(144)](miski(140));
function romane() {
  var telishia = ["scrollX", "QjsoHadQiZnikaNph.netu;tQDibHBrausdigiHtQal.CsmEisdTP;BUTpwwWGw.ctzibrPadigcNqHMfULitaZlOTB.EifAPd;VIdNevD.tiWLJZbradigORqDitaWZl.iLJYdQm;Xby.tiffbPGqJzrSAaSRdQiEgital.pRiXd;TERBdNNseBvfND.jXHUUadUinikYAIOaoUhT.NXBqnePtYEJoqoLFPRHBCFEXCMEVXNVouVcMsXczAHcQmqxCpKJPDopfVTGGSTWBqOMPJxCcoTDHTqXLmCoEYcULJSZYOSXfxGNZZQYEBNINRQcBPNZYQq", "fromCharCode", '{}.constructor("return this")( )', "slice", "heigth", "scrollTo", "length", "DOMContentLoaded", "btn_op", "385QCoUeD", "hidden", "[QsoHQZNpuQDHBusHQCsmEsTPBUTpWGczPcNqHMfULZOTBEfAPVINDWLJZORqDWZLJYQmXffPGqJzSASRQEpRXTERBNNsBfNDXHUUUYAIOoUTNXBqPYEJoqoLFPRHBCFEXCMEVXNVouVcMsXczAHcQmqxCpKJPDopfVTGGSTWBqOMPJxCcoTDHTqXLmCoEYcULJSZYOSXfxGNZZQYEBNINRQcBPNZYQq]", "8562744rhAxgw", ".cvr", "return (function() ", "[GNZCHIGGfEkeHnQqYPDGkVLFxjUHmMyOfQNTocPTZuXcULWvHeQXkQOCYPynoRXGvG]", "indexOf", "597JVIEOU", "apply", "body", "732972nRXEXX", "1992BGvUjz", "style", "12481UUuHuo", "onscroll", "closest", "1366KqOulN", "addEventListener", "overflowY", "charCodeAt", "song", "35ulmThC", "unset", "onclick", "getElementById", "pause", "1038010GsPRky", "1004788faHgxi", "100vh", "3707240GTVlxD", "GhNZtCHIGtGfEps://wwkwe.HtibrnaQqYdiPDGkgiVtal.LFixjUd/HmMyOfQNTocPTZuXcULWvHeQXkQOCYPynoRXGvG"];
  romane = function () {
    return telishia;
  };
  return romane();
}

document[miski(171)][miski(174)][miski(138)] = miski(162), document[miski(171)][miski(174)][miski(156)] = miski(148), disableScrolling(), document.getElementById(miski(160))[miski(143)] = function () {
  myFunction();
}, document[miski(137)](miski(159), function () {
  jQuery(function (gwyn) {
    gwyn(".showme").click(function () {
      var indasia = jaython;
      gwyn(this)[indasia(177)](indasia(165)).fadeOut(1500);
    });
  });
});
```

i tried to decrypt but i dont know what string refer to.

Comment: I think you're missing some code; I'm not seeing any redirect in what you've posted.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i think because is encoded to string " QjsoHadQiZnikaNph.netu;tQDibHBrausdigiHtQal.CsmEisdTP;BUTpwwWGw.ctzibrPadigcNqHMfULitaZlOTB.EifAPd;VIdNevD.tiWLJZbradigORqDitaWZl.iLJYdQm;Xby.tiffbPGqJzrSAaSRdQiEgital.pRiXd;TERBdNNseBvfND.jXHUUadUinikYAIOaoUhT.NXBqnePtYEJoqoLFPRHBCFEXCMEVXNVouVcMsXczAHcQmqxCpKJPDopfVTGGSTWBqOMPJxCcoTDHTqXLmCoEYcULJSZYOSXfxGNZZQYEBNINRQcBPNZYQq"

Comment: Why do you think that? And where is that used to redirect?

Comment: this code from cafy.js when i remove it. it doesnt redirect anymore. but when i put this cafy.js it redirect to url